# Loading bar still running in Firefox if previous page is clicked

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a progress 'bar' that works fine in IE and Chrome. When you click on a link or input button with submit, a progress 'bar' is called via JQuery. But the behaviour in Firefox is not what i was expecting.

This is my script:

```
$("a, input[type=submit]").click( // http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/
  function () {
    if ($(this).attr('target') == '_blank' || $(this).hasClass("noloadingbar")) {
    }
    else {
      var cl = new CanvasLoader('canvasloader-container');
      cl.setDiameter(65); // default is 40
      cl.setDensity(50); // default is 40
      cl.setRange(0.8); // default is 1.3
      cl.setFPS(29); // default is 24
      cl.show(); // Hidden by default

      // This bit is only for positioning - not necessary
      var loaderObj = document.getElementById("canvasLoader");
      loaderObj.style.position = "absolute";
      loaderObj.style["top"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
      loaderObj.style["left"] = cl.getDiameter() * -0.5 + "px";
    }
  }
)
```

When i click on a link in Firefox, the progress 'bar' is loading, just like in IE and Chrome. But when I click on the previous button (previous page), the progress 'bar' in Firefox is starting up again.

How can I make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: It's not only this progress 'bar'. If you put an $( "div.row" ).append( "<p>Testing, still standing</p>" ), it is still visible on the previous page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the trick, after leaving the page, tell de progress bar to stop.

```
$(window).unload(function(){ 
  c1.stop(); 
});
```

Will be:

```
$(document).on('click','a, input[type=submit]',function(){ // Aan de hand van een klik de functie oproepen
  if ($(this).attr('target') == '_blank' || $(this).hasClass("noloadingbar")) {}
  else {
    var cl = new CanvasLoader('canvasloader-container');
    cl.show(); // Hidden by default

    $(window).unload(function(){ // Anders stop Firefox niet als je pagina terug gaat
      c1.stop();
    });
  }
});
```